# DELETE request pending for a long time then fails

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, ubuntu-12.04

I am playing with nodejs/expressjs/angularjs with MondgoDB on Ubuntu 12.04. I was going through this [example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/). When I tested this locally, deleting a wine worked just fine. But after deploying to Ubuntu 12.04 box, DELETE request failed. I am using nginx as proxy and running nodejs on port 3000.

I tried to stop nginx and running it directly on nodejs on different port. It didn't help; proves me that this problem has nothing to do with nginx.

But using curl I was able to delete an item. e.g. `curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/wines/5069b47aa892630aae000007.`

So am I missing something in middle-tier(expressjs)? Here is my [sandbox](http://www.workopenly.com/wines).

Comment: If you stop nginx and post the request directly to nodejs, does it work?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum edited. I wasn't clear about that part. No, it did not work.

Comment: Post the code for your express app, please. You are probably failing to call `res.send` correctly, or you have some middleware in place that never calls `next()`.

Comment: Also saying "failed" is less helpful that saying specifically what happened using technical terms and/or error messages.

Comment: It did not work at work, but it worked at home without any code change. This could be somehow "network" related? I am going to validate this again tomorrow at work again.